# checking for a specific gesture recognizer

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I'm looking at some existing code that adds a pinchGestureRecognizer at a specific zoom level of a scrollView.  (Like when the scrollView.zoomScale > 10).  At this zoom level, the pinch gesture does some special handling with a (`handlePinch:` selector)on the scrollView on the pinch.

I'm tasked to have a slider emulate the zooming of the scrollView so the user doesn't have to use two fingers to pinch all the time to zoom.  I'd like to add the pinchGesture when my zoomScale is > 10 for the scrollView to get the same special handling.  I don't want to add two of the same gestureRecognizers since I am assuming that if I blindly add it when the zoomScale > 10, I'm going to get unwanted behavior.  I don't know how to check for a specific gesture in this case.

I basically want to do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
if (slider.value > .6 && slider.value < .8) {
    // check for pinch gesture

   // I thought I could get the NSArray of gestures from my self.scrollView and check if it's empty, but there are other gestures are already attached to the scrollView.
   // I thought I could also try self.scrollView respondsToSelector:@selector(handlePinch:), but I don't think that works.

    //self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (yourPinchRecognizer == nil) {
    // do something
}
```

This has worked for me with the app I am working on.